# two PHPSimpleHtmlDom conditions in one foreach loop

Tags: php, parsing, foreach, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHPSimpleHTMLDOM Parser and I'd like to somehow implement a foreach loop with two conditions.  I'm getting the headlines that I want, but I also want to get the href which applies to that particular headline.  If I write a nested foreach loop for the href alone, it loops way too many times and outputs many duplicates.  Here's my code:

```
include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('somehtml.com');

  foreach ($html->find('ul[class=headlines] li') as $return){
    //if I put another foreach here, too many duplicates
    echo $return;
  }
```

The other foreach loop looks like this:

```
foreach ($html->find('ul[class=headlines] li a') as $href){
  $link = $href->href;
  echo $link;
}
```

How can I put these two conditions into one foreach loop so the link corresponds to the correct article and I can pass it along to another php file to do something with it?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a suggestion. Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Can you be more specific?  How would I do that?

Comment: Search on google and here. There are lot of examples. I used it to extract anchor links from a page. You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php) for more info on cURL. I am not giving a solution, its just a suggestion as I said earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul class="headlines">
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>   
    <li><a href="http://bing.com">Bing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you have to traverse all of the `li` items and fetch their nth child which corresponds to the `a` tag (in this case it is the first one) like that:

```
foreach ($html->find('ul[class=headlines] li') as $return){
    $a = $return->children(0);
    echo 'Link: ' . $a->href . '<br />';
    echo 'Headline: ' . $a->plaintext . '<br />';
}
```

Note that you could simply print out `$a` here, without fetching the link and the headline separately.

I would suggest you to use some native extension based on [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) for better performance, such as [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). You also can combine it with XPath to make things simpler.