# Erlang & Yaws installation

Tags: web, erlang, chat, yaws

I want to apologize about my English. It's not very good.

So, I want to make a chat application (pretty much like Facebook's), and after reading a lot I decided to make this chat app with Erlang. After more reading I found out that I can use Yaws server to make a web application with Erlang, but that's all. I still can't even install and configure it well. So my questions are:

1. Is this information correct? Do I need Erlang / Yaws to create this chat app?
2. If it's correct, how do I install and configure it under Windows 7? I've tried to simply install "OTP 17.0 Windows 32-bit Binary File" from here http://www.erlang.org/download.html and "Yaws-1.98-windows-installer.exe" from  http://yaws.hyber.org/download/, but I think something went wrong, because after I "configure it" at localhost port 8001/8080 or others still nothing happens. So what's next? Do I have to install my code in special directories and/or what do I have to do next ?
3. In case I finally get a Chat application in Erlang ready, how can It interface with my PHP code? I mean, I already have the PHP project. It is a normal web project with PHP/HTML/Javascript, etc. so my question is, how do I glue these two elements together?(I would like to stress one more time that I have to make something like the Facebook chat).

I'll be thankful for all kind of information, tutorials, books, videos, anything.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you, Erlang is an excellent option for a chat server. If you want to go for Yaws, check the [documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yaws.pdf), it support external scripts via CGI and Websockets. All the information you need to communicate your PHP application with your chat Application is on chapter 9 of yaws' pdf documentation.

There are many ways to create a web application in Erlang.  Here are some old examples that use mochiweb:

http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-kserl/source_code

http://www.chrismoos.com/2009/09/28/building-an-erlang-chat-server-with-comet-part-1/

and a nice example from [erlang central](http://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=Chatservercorrected%20spelling,%20fixed%20grammar)

Regarding the PHP integration,there are again, several ways to communicate both. You can integrate the chat with your PHP code using a [PHP Erlang bridge](https://github.com/videlalvaro/mypeb)

or using [websockets](https://github.com/jimmyrcom/HTML5-Canvas-Old-School-RPG-Map-with-Erlang-Websockets-Chat)

or probably you could try to send your data encoded in JSON from mochiweb using mochijson2.erl and communicate both by HTTP using [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php) from PHP.

All in all, I would probably also use yaws since is well documented and easy to use. Good luck

Comment: For more advanced information on the topic of how erlang is used to build massive chat systems, check out Rick Reed's (from Whatsapp) from Erlang Factory San Francisco 2014: http://www.erlang-factory.com/sfbay2014/rick-reed  (slides and video linked from here)

Comment: The answer above neglects to mention that Yaws specifically supports PHP as well, see [the Yaws PDF documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yaws.pdf) for more details. It also supports websockets.

Comment: Thank you for the support, but i still cant install, configure and use Erlang well. I mean, okay Erlang is installed, but I'm still confused about how to install and configure that Yaws.

And have one more question. Okay Yaws is Erlang web server, but do i need web framework like Nitrogen or Chicago Boss or other? Or i need just Yaws or just some Framework. And how to make all this stuffs works together.

Again, I'm sorry about my stupid/nooby questions.