# Unable to use file_get_contents(), returns nothing

Tags: php

I'm trying to get some data from a website that is not mine, using this code.

```
<?
$text = file_get_contents("https://ninjacourses.com/explore/4/");
echo $text;
?>
```

However, nothing is being echo'd, and the string length is 0.

I've done this method before, and it has worked no problem, but with this website, it is not working at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think it will work very well with HTTPS... The manual says it returns false on failure - would pay to var_dump() the output to be sure. See [this article here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https) too for a similar case.

Comment: Have you enabled `allow_url_fopen` in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: If you enable error_reporting you will se the following error: `SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Comment: I have enabled `allow_url_fopen`. It's on by default.

Comment: you con't ..you have to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the contents using `curl` like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ninjacourses.com/explore/4/");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

cURL is a way you can hit a URL from your code to get a html response from it. cURL means client URL which allows you to connect with other URLs and use their responses in your code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ninjacourses.com/explore/4/");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

i think this is useful for you [curl-with-php](http://codular.com/curl-with-php) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php)