# SSL error curl php

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to get a website content using curl in PHP.

Here's my code:

```
$sslVersion = 1;
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, $sslVersion);

//execute post
$response = curl_exec($ch);

//response
echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
echo PHP_EOL;

//response
echo 'Response: ';
var_dump($response);
echo PHP_EOL;

curl_close($ch);
```

If I have my SSL version set to 1 I get:

```
Error: error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000)
Response: bool(false)
```

If it's 2 I have:

```
Error: OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support
Response: bool(false)
```

And if it's 3 this happens:

```
Error: Empty reply from server
Response: bool(false)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why are using sslVersion ???

Comment: you can check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096134/unable-to-use-file-get-contents-returns-nothing/27096348#27096348)

Comment: @RajibGhosh Thanks but this is not really my problem, I'n using sslVersion because I have a different error in function of version

Comment: @Ajouve hi did you solve the issue? thanks