# How to use HTML Form instead of AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

1. I cant use AJAX (XMLHTTPRequest) because of Same-Origin-Policy.
2. I cant access the Server internals, neither do I have the
   Server-Code.
3. The Server only supports HTTPMethods: `POST, OPTIONS`
4. I cannot use a third server (e.g. for using curl)

I can use a form-Post

```
<form method="post" action="some-web-server.com/something.JSON">
  <input name="param" value="some JSON param" />
</form>
```

to get the answer but I getting redirected to the JSON.page to get the answer.
Is there a possibility to get the response in JS? something like that:

```
<form target="javascript: someFunctionUsingTheResponse(this.submit())" method="post" action="someServer/st.JSON" >
```

and in the HTML-Head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function someFunctionUsingTheResponse(text){
    alert(text);
  }
</script>
```

UPDATE:
I already tried to create an `<iframe name="dummy">` and setting the target of the form to this dummy-iframe `<form target="dummy">` which works quite good (in Chrome, not working in IE), but i still cannot access the data of the iFrame using JS. (origin Policy)

Comment: do you have a server side part of your code? You could send the ajax request to your own server and do a `curl` from there to get the answer from the remote JSON and then return that value to your front-end.

Comment: `jsonp` is what you need

Comment: `jsonp` is great but as far as I know the remote server has to support it or it won't work, i.e. wrap everything in the callback param, so it might not be an option for OP.

Comment: @martincarlin87 no, cant access the server-code, my own server would then need to be in the same domain as the `some-web-server`, right? I cannot access any server in this domain.

Comment: no, if you do the `curl` from the server side then it's fine even if it's a different domain (as long as you can access it and it's not blocked from the outside etc). An example of what curl is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php

Comment: You can send request to your own server and then use curl to send request to another server.
Request:
browser->own server(ajax)->different server(curl)
Response:
browser<-own server(ajax response)<-different server(curl response)

Comment: @OlegMeleshko can I use JSONP with a POST-Request?

Comment: @martincarlin87 Unfortunately I am not allowed to use a third server, in order to use curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to get the response in JS?

No. A regular form submission does not make the data available to JS.

Any means of getting the data in JS will be subject to the same origin policy.

There are various [ways to circumvent the same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) but a regular form submission to the target URL is not one of them.

Answer (score -1):

The form element should be like this:

```
<form onsubmit="someFunctionUsingTheResponse()">
```

You can use this as your function:

```
function someFunctionUsingTheResponse(){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "some-web-server.com/something.JSON", false );
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: First Line of the Question: Cant use AJAX, because of Same-Origin Policy