# Could not include codeigniter controller files in external php script

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

i have used this code form external php script to include the codeigniter controller file.

```
include_once "codeigniter/index.php/user";
```

it doesn't work.

`'user'` is my controller file.

However i can include by making `'user'` the default controller page

```
$route['default_controller']="user";
```

and use  as:

```
include_once "codeigniter/index.php";
```

but what if i need other controller files?

**update:**

Also, the controller file could be linked through external php script:

```
<a href="codeigniter/index.php/user">click here</a>
```

Comment: include_once "../codeigniter/index.php/user"; try this

Comment: You need to refer documentation. This is a completely wrong way. Never include controller in any file.

Comment: that too is not working.

Comment: oh. then how can i include that from external php script. isn't there any way?

Comment: Why not use HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc to call controller much easier. Normal codeigniter you will not be able to.

Comment: @RaviHirani how could i do then?

Comment: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter can be told to load a default controller when a URI is not present, as will be the case when only your site root URL is requested. To specify a default controller, open your `application/config/routes.php` file and set this variable:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'User';
```

Where `User` is the name of the controller class you want used. If you now load your main `index.php` file without specifying any URI segments you'll see your Hello World message by default.

In your case, you can call any controller by:-

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/controller_name/method_name/
```

This [tutorial link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) will explain better :)

To call CI controller outside you should use [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php).

```
  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'Your_CI_CONTROLLER_URL');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);
  if (empty($buffer)){
      print "Nothing returned from url.<p>";
  }
  else{
      print $buffer;
  }
```

Comment: what if i need other controller files than 'user'?

Comment: you can call other controller by:- 
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/controller_name/method_name/

Comment: from external php script??

Comment: You need to use cURL for this fnctionality. using cURL you can call CI controller method and pass parameters into it.

Comment: .thanks. but see in the 2nd last paragraph of the question and how i did it for 'user'.  And there could be the way to include other controller files.

Comment: this is not the right way. Never include controller in any file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100960/discussion-between-sanzeeb-aryal-and-ravi-hirani).