# how to use multiple controllers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers

i am currently working on a project in codeigniter. I want to separate my controllers for each function.

Example,

```
controller_for_login.php
controller_for_redirecting_to_other_views.php
controller_for_CRUD.php
controller_for_others.php
```

is there any way to make it like this one? so that my codes will be a lot organized. thanks.

Comment: Refer this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/34850721/4198099

Comment: work through the tutorial in the codeigniter user guide and this will become much clearer how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy

1)First create a new file in controller folder e.g `Classname.php`

2)Edit that file

```
class Classname Extends CI_Controller
{
}
```

3) Put your new functions inside this class file

Put the class file into library folder
the file like this

```
class Authenticate {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();

    }
  public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $sessionid = $this->ci->session->userdata('moderId');
        if($sessionid)
        {
        return isset($sessionid);
        }
         else if(!$sessionid) {
      redirect(base_url() . 'moderator');
 }
    }
}
```

And in the controller file, call that class function like this

```
class B2bcategory extends CI_Controller {    
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->authenticate->is_logged_in();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already do it. the problem is, i cannot call another class from another controller.

Comment: create that class in library folder. and call it in your controller   $this->authenticate->is_logged_in();

Comment: hi kev_m, please put the class file into library folder,am edited my answer,check it