# PHP cURL, POST JSON getting error in php curl

Tags: php, json, curl

```
curl  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"firstname":"Mike","lastname":"Doel","customer_id":"12345","email":"test_api_user@gmail.com.com"}' -u API-key:  APIURL(http://)
```

above statement is running well in command but i am unable to achive the same by php code below is my code

```
$url="https://apiurl"; 

$data=array("firstname"=>"Mike","lastname"=>"Doel","customer_id"=>"12345","email"=>"test_api_user@gmail.com");

$data_json=json_encode($data); 

//Curl code

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',"Accept: application/json","api-key")); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: have pass any userid or password for api key?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In CURL, for api key you need to pass username:password , if you going to access in php code 

$url="https://apiurl"; 
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'username:password',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300000,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

return $response;
```

Try it once..hopefully it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array([..snip..], "api-key")); 
                                                          ^^^^^
```

and

```
curl [..snip..] -u api-key
                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

are **NOT** equivalent. `-u` specifies HTTP Basic authentication, with `username:password`. Your setopt is just stuffing that username as the NAME of an http header, which is not how basic auth credentials show up

You should have

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "api-key");
```

instead.