# php base64_encode image displayed on the site from external website

Tags: php, base64, preg-replace, preg-match, file-get-contents

I am getting content from my first website and displaying it on my other website by using `file_get_contents()` and I am using `preg_replace()` and `preg_match()` to modify the output the way I want it.

Now, there are images I would like to `base64_encode()` but I am stuck on figuring out how to do that?

If I use this line of code:

```
preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $fourth_content, $out)
```

I can print out all images `src` but it cannot encode them and send them back to the src.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: i think you need to get the image file contents from `src` using `file_get_contents()` and then try to encode the image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise to think in steps. What is it you have to do?

1. Fetch HTML from remote URL `complete`
2. Grab every image `complete`
3. Display every image `todo`

You have the image URLs, now what? You want to iterate over every image.

Sidenote: Every image you want to grab means a new HTTP request (download). This quickly builds up loading time. Think: is this what I want? If so, then let's break it down:

**Step 1**

Get HTML from URL.

```
<?php
    // Your URL
    $url = 'https://twitter.com/dogethedog';

    // Get HTML from your URL
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
```

**Step 2**

Grab every image.

```
    // Grab every image source
    preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $data, $out);
```

**Step 3a**

Do this for every image URL we got.

```
    // Loop over every image source
    foreach($out[1] as $imageURL){
```

**Step 3b**

Download the image data from our URL.

For a Base64 encoded image to display, we also need the content type of the image. This can be grabbed with PHP function `curl_getinfo()`.

[More info about Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

[More info about cURL, it's safer with e.g. images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php)

```
         // Use cURL to fetch image data and image type
         // We need image type to be able to properly display jpg, png, gif, ...
         $ch        = curl_init($imageURL);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // For https/ssl
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // Standard cURL Option

         // Fetch cURL Content
         $imageData = curl_exec($ch);
         $imageType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

         // Close cURL Session
         curl_close($ch);
```

**Step 3c**

Now that we have the data and image type, properly render the `<img>` tag.

```
         // Image data gets to be fetched as BLOB, we need Base64
         $imageDataEncoded = base64_encode($imageData);

         // Build HTML <img> tag with proper type and base encoded image data
         ?>

         <img src="data:<?php print $imageType ?>;base64,<?php print $imageDataEncoded ?>" alt="Could not fetch image">

         <?php

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Joachim! I will test this :)