# How to append a page to generate page views?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

This code appends iframe after set intervals:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function random_no(){
    var ran=Math.random();
    jQuery('#random_no_container').html(ran);
    }

    window.setInterval(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var pagivews;
    pageviews = '<iframe src="#" width="100%" height="100%">'+'<'+'/iframe>' 
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ifdiv').append(pageviews)
    });
    });      random_no();
    }, 10000);  // Change Interval here to test. For eg: 5000 for 5 sec
    </script>

    <div id="ifdiv"></div>
```

Is it possible to append a html page to get a pageviews within a page?

Comment: *THIS CODE APPENDS IFRAME AFTER SET INTERVALS:* - Must you yell at us? That is what CAPS are.

Comment: what is the relation to php? or are you not going to bother commenting?

Comment: Bro my programming language is weak. Sorry if i tagged in wrong programming. Thank you. @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'Page View'?
What you are doing is rendering iFrames to your page.
If you want to get 'Page Views' for a page the best way to do it is generating requests to the page - that can be done in multiple ways (here is the php way):

PHP: use [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php) inside a loop to create requests to that page. (This can be achieved also without curl)

```
// Make a HTTP GET request and print it (requires allow_url_fopen to be enabled)
print file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: i want to generate more pageviews to improve CPM without distracting visitor by appending a page within a page.