# PHP Paypal List payments curl

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Please help me how to use this in PHP curl

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment?count=10&start_index=0&sort_by=create_time&sort_order=desc \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is cURL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use any of the existing SDKs for Paypal?

Comment: I used postman, problem solved :D