# saving form data using curl to controller in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, curl

There is a form and i am getting $_POST data.
The code is this

```
   if (isset($_POST) && $_POST) {
        $fields = $_POST;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.org/index.php/public/example/SaveExample");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
    }
```

But the call to controller is not working.what will be the issue.anybody pls help

Comment: anybody pls help.i am new to this.

Comment: Where do you want to send the data and what is the error you're facing? Please clarify.

Comment: i want to pass the posted data to controller.i am using curl for it.saveExample is my function in controller.now that call is not working.that function is not calling.when submitting form.only a refresh is happening.values are not entering to database.

Comment: Ok, but why CURL? This operation can be performed easily without it.

Comment: see, when to use curl - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php