# Getting data from a curl query

Tags: php, html, curl

so here is the url for curl -> `curl 'https://api.xyz.com/v2.1/messages?limit=2&start_date=2021-01-01&end_date=2021-12-12' -u user:pass`

When I run this i get some results in the content option. any suggestions on how to display those datas through an array in html page?(php code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is cURL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062324/what-is-curl-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Can you make the http request directly from PHP? If so, [Php Curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) or [File_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) should meet your needs. A simple example might look like:

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'));
    print_r($data);
```